# Select first element with a specified class, and if none select another element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to highlight the first link with the class 'main' inside a div, and if there is none, just highlight the first link

ie:

```
<div class="group1">
 <a href="product1">product1</a>
 <a href="product2" class="main">product2</a>
 <a href="product3">product3</a>
</div>

<div class="group2">
 <a href="product1">product1</a>
 <a href="product2">product2</a>
 <a href="product3">product3</a>
</div>
```

So in `group1 product2` will get the highlight and in `group2` it will be `product1`

Right now I'm doing it this way:

```
 obj=$('.group2 a.main').first();
 if (obj.length==0) {obj=$('.group2 a').first();}
 obj.css('color','red');
```

But I was wondering if there's a more compact way to do it.

```
$('.group1 a.main,.group1 a').first().css('color','red')
```

Doesn't works, as jquery returns the elements in document order and that would give a wrong result

Comment: Ummmm reading the answers so far, seems that you always have to use a conditional in one or another way. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('div[class^=group] a')
    .filter(':has(a.main) a.main, :not(:has(a.main)) a:first-child')
    .css({color:'red'})
```

as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/6AWmq/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
 obj=$('.group2 a.main').eq(0).css({'color':'red'});
```

or

```
obj=$('.group2 a.main').eq(0).style('color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the pseudo class first :

```
$('.group2 a.main:first').css({'color':'red'});
```

Or with a variable it should be :

```
$obj = $('.group2 a.main:first');
if(!$obj.length)
    $obj = $('.group2 a:first');
$obj.css('color','red');
```

If you need to do this on each group, that'll give :

```
$('div[class^=group]').each(function(i, e) { 
    $obj = $(e).find('a.main:first');
    if(!$obj.length)
        $obj = $(e).find('a:first');
    $obj.css('color','red');
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/MMGM4/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){  
    // Iterating over each div
    $('div').each(function(){  

       if($(this).find('a.main:first').length){
         // If any hyperlink with class main is present
         $(this).find('a.main:first').css({'color':'red'});
       }else{
         // Select any hyperlink
         $(this).find('a:first').css({'color':'red'});
       }

    });   
 });
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h27w4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
var obj = $('div[class^="group"]');
obj.each(function(){
   if($('a',this).hasClass('main')){
      $('.main').css('color','red');
   }else{
      $('a:first',this).css('color','red');
   }
});
```

#### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NV68M/)